# Effect of a CDN on latency of an overseas web server

Tags: cdn, ping, latency

I'm trying to understand the effect a CDN can have on latency. I tried pinging three different web servers, two of which are based in France. Here are the results I got at the time of the test:

average latency for nytimes.com: 20.764 ms

average latency for lemonde.fr: 22.842 ms

average latency for liberation.fr: 115.805 ms

Does this mean that the Le Monde server is sitting behind a CDN to lower latency?

I realize I should have ran the tests at the same local time in France that I ran them here, but I didn't feel like waiting until tomorrow to do it right, still I was struck by the difference between the results I got for lemonde.fr vs. liberation.fr, as well as the similarity between the results for lemonde.fr and nytimes.com.

So are the lower-than-expected results for lemonde.fr the result of the Le Monde server sitting behind a CDN?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole theory of a CDN (content delivery network) is that visitors can access a site from a server closer to their location than to the source, assuming they are some distance away.  The net effect is to lower the latency.  You should be able to check if lemonde is using a CDN by looking at the nameservers and A Record RDNS.  here's one way to do it https://intodns.com/lemonde.fr

In the case of lemonde, they are using fastly CDN.  There is no definitive answer as to whether or not that is why ping is quicker, but it is likely to be so.

Comment: ICMP pings don't necessarily take the same routes and hit up the same servers as a TCP/IP packet would (such as one used in an HTTP(s) request). As such, it's possible to get different results from ping than in actual use. Probably not an issue in this case, but worth knowing if you're trying to test something.